# Scrapy: Include items with 404 status code when sending to database via pipeline

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

Using Scrapy in a python 2.x environment, I have a spider set up to scrape a list of webpages, specifically to see if any of those pages produce an error, such as 400/404/500.

I've written the scrapy project with the intention that all scraped results are stored in an mysql database, via the pipeline.
And it works! I'm able to write to my database successfully. But only with successfully-scraped pages, with HTTP status code 200.

Scrapy does not seem to be sending information on 404 pages through the pipeline and into the database.

Below is an extraction from the spider's code, which scrapes two webpages that don't exist:

```
class LandingPage004Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name='LandingPage004Spider'
start_urls = []

def __init__(self):
    super(LandingPage004Spider,self).__init__()
    #self.start_urls = unique_landingpages
    self.start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/doesntexist', 'https://www.google.com/deadpage']

def parse(self, response):
    url = response.url
    url_title = 'Title goes here.'
    pagesize = len(response.body)
    HTTP_code = response.status
    yield {'url': url, "pagesize": pagesize, "HTTP_code": HTTP_code}
```

When I run this spider, I get the following output:

```
[scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <404 https://www.google.com/deadpage>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
[scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <404 https://www.google.com/doesntexist>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Now, I've done some heavy searching on this, and it seems like this might be on purpose, and that there's a way to force scrapy to include 404s. I see there's an option, **dont_filter**, but I can only find directions on how to append that code to code syntax similar to:
yield Request(url="test.com", callback=self.callback, dont_filter = True)

But my spider's structure doesn't seem to allow for any such line.

Am I correct that the 404s aren't being sent to the database, by design?
Is there a way to append my current code to allow 404s to be recorded?

In case it's of help, here is the pipelines.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from LandingPageVerifier.models import LandingPagesScrapeResults, db_connect

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Landingpageverifier004Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    session = self.Session()
    landingpage_scrape_results = LandingPagesScrapeResults()
    landingpage_scrape_results.url = item["url"]
    landingpage_scrape_results.client_id = 1
    landingpage_scrape_results.HTTP_code = item["HTTP_code"]
    landingpage_scrape_results.page_size = item["pagesize"]

    try:
        session.add(landingpage_scrape_results)
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

    return item
```

and an excerpt from my models.py file:

```
class LandingPagesScrapeResults(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'landingpages_scrape_results'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('landingpages_clients.id'))
    url = Column(String(512), nullable=True)
    url_shortener = Column(String(32), nullable=True)
    url_title = Column(String(256), nullable=True)
    page_size = Column(Integer(), nullable=True)
    created_on = Column(DateTime(),default=datetime.datetime.now)
    HTTP_code = Column(String(4), nullable=True)
    err_small = Column(String(1), nullable=True)
    err_has_not_found = Column(String(1), nullable=True)
    err_has_error = Column(String(1), nullable=True)
    err_has_nolongeravailable  = Column(String(1), nullable=True)
    err_no_service_specials = Column(String(1), nullable=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [HttpErrorMiddleware docs](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror):

> According to the HTTP standard, successful responses are those whose
>   status codes are in the 200-300 range.
>
> If you still want to process response codes outside that range, you
>   can specify which response codes the spider is able to handle using
>   the `handle_httpstatus_list` spider attribute or `HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES`
>   setting.
>
> For example, if you want your spider to handle 404 responses you can
>   do this:
>
> ```
> class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
>     handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
> ```
>
> The `handle_httpstatus_list` key of `Request.meta` can also be used to specify which response codes to allow
>   on a per-request basis. You can also set the meta key
>   `handle_httpstatus_all` to `True` if you want to allow any response code
>   for a request.
>
> Keep in mind, however, that it’s usually a bad idea to handle non-200
>   responses, unless you really know what you’re doing.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
Agreed that it's usually a bad idea to handle non-200's. Noted. 
Thanks again!!

Answer (score 5):

@stranac gave a great answer of course, but you can also handle this directly with the `errback` Request attribute, which will catch all bad responses, specifically in the request you need it:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield Request(
        'http://httpbin.org/status/404', 
        errback=self.parse_error, 
        callback=self.parse_item,
    )

def parse_error(self, failure):
    if failure.value.response.status == 404:
        # insert item as a bad response

def parse_item(self, response):
    # insert item as good response
```

Or you can also of course always use a Middleware, to catch every kind of response/request as soon as it is received.

Comment: Do you have an example of middleware implementation?

Comment: check the [scrapy-plugins](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins) repos, and [here are](https://github.com/scrapinghub/testspiders/blob/master/testspiders/middleware.py) some very simple ones too.